# MailChimp v3 API - Adding to Groups

Tags: mailchimp

Is there a way to manage a subscribers' group preference for lists in the v3 API? MailChimp documentation is a little light on the subject.

Comment: Do you mean setting their group values whenever you add them through the API? Because I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, by assigning the member to an interest.

---

You have to find out the ID of the group (called 'interests') that you are wanting to add to. Unfortunately this cannot be found anywhere on the MailChimp dashboard.

The easiest way to find out the 'interest' ID (rather than creating a script) is to go to the [MailChimp playground](https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/playground/) and then, after entering in your API key, route to...

`lists > the list in question > members (in the sub-resources dropdown)`

then...

`load (in the actions dropdown) for any member`

or

`Create Members (button)`

The page will load the member's details. Scroll down until you see the 'interests' array/object. There you will see the IDs. Notice they can be set to true or false.

> You will have to figure out which ID relates to what 'group'/'interest' by making the call, and then looking at the member's details via your MailChimp dashboard.

So when it comes to actually making the **POST** call ('member' create), you would want something on the lines of...

```
{
  "email_address":"example@freddiesjokes.com",
  "status":"subscribed",
  "interests": {
    "b8a9d7cbf6": true
  },
# ADDITIONAL FIELDS, IF REQUIRED...
  "merge_fields":{
    "FNAME": "foo bar",
    "LNAME": "foo bar",
    "MERGE3": "foo bar",
    "MERGE4": "foo bar"
  }
}
```

A **PUT** call ('member' edit) example...

```
{
  "interests": {
    "b8a9d7cbf6": false,
    "5998e44916": true
  }
}
```

> For **PUT** requests, it seems that you must declare every 'interest' and state whether it is true or false.

Comment: Thanks! I've actually had success in POST requests only specifying interests to add, rather than all interests.

Comment: No probs   Cool but notice I am referring to PUT requests

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant, though I don't think it's fully clear that the final note only applies to PUT calls. You also list both interests in your POST example, which in my experience isn't necessary.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are looking for: [Lists Interest Categories Collection](http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/resources/lists/interest-categories/lists-interest-categories-collection)

In that endpoint you can get and create new groups for lists. And here [Lists Interests Collection](http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/resources/lists/interest-categories/interests/lists-interests-collection) you can get interests or create new ones.

```
Lemonades
    Coca Cola
    Pepsi Max
    Fanta
```

Lemonades represents *category* or better a group name. Cola, pepsi and fanta represents *interests* or better group items in that spesific group/category.

Hope this helps :)